# VSInstallDir missing

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using VS 2010 and Windows 7.  I'm trying to run a homework problem for a class in 3D Graphics, but when I try to run the downloaded homework program, I get this error: "VSInstallDir is missing or empty".  When I click on the solution's properties, I don't find a place to enter this variable.  Homework is due 12/19, so there's a bit of a time crunch. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

It may refer to an environment variable named 'VSInstallDir'

If your homework program uses command-line Visual Studio tools,
 you can try to run it from the 'Visual Studio command prompt' (search for it using your Windows start menu).

Another option is to manually add it in Windows using System Properties (Windows Key + Break keyboard shortcut), goto Advanced, Environment variables, User variables and add it there.
It's value should be 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\' without the quotes if you have 64-bit windows or 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\' if you have 32-bit windows installed. You will have to restart Visual Studio for this.