# Visual Studio has an error with Ogre3D sample (VSInstallDir issue)

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I want to run Ogre3D sample in Visual Studio. I did set and add the sample path to system path but when I run the sample, it shows this message:

> cannot launch the debugger.the required property 'VSInstallDir' is
>   missing or empty.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

As outlined by [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345435/vsinstalldir-missing): The environment variable named 'VSInstallDir' is missing. Have a look at the other answer for details on how to fix it.

BTW: This is not an Ogre3D issue, as it would affect any other application as well.