# Why the Vs2013 can't find the right folder for `$(VSINSTALLDIR)` in 'ExtensionTargets' itemgroup

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, directx

When the vs2013 project has the section:

```
<ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
<Import Project="$(VSINSTALLDIR)\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\VsGraphics\ImageContentTask.targets" />
<Import Project="$(VSINSTALLDIR)\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\VsGraphics\MeshContentTask.targets" />
<Import Project="$(VSINSTALLDIR)\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\VsGraphics\ShaderGraphContentTask.targets" />
</ImportGroup>
```

The `$(VSINSTALLDIR)` is replaced with `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\`,
I don't know why the Vs2013 can't find the right folder for `$(VSINSTALLDIR)` .

Edit：I found the `$(VSINSTALLDIR)` in vs2013 commandline as follow:
[image]

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345435/vsinstalldir-missing

Comment: @l19 I used the vs2013 cmd found the `$(VSINSTALLDIR)` as the figure in question.